# Ubuntu Boot Woes

Tags: boot

I have a problem that goes back to my initial install of Ubuntu 14 about 2 years ago. I currently have Ubuntu 17.04. Unknown to me the install program selected my data disc (500gb internal) to install Grub. That drive is beginning to fail. If I remove the data drive I can boot to Win10 which I seldom use, but I get no BIOS options to boot to Ubuntu. Reinstall the drive and it's like nothing ever happened.

I'd just like an easy-peasy way to make my main drive (480gb SSD) a stand-alone boot drive.

Anyone got an easy answer? I looked into this about a year ago when I first discovered this problem. Since the data drive was working fine then I kicked the can so to speak. I cannot do that any longer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the Ubuntu install on the data disk also?  Can you boot Windows through grub now?

Comment: The install is on the SSD drive. All of the normal folders that Ubuntu/Linux installs is on the SSD drive, I'm just missing Grub on the SSD. With the data drive off the only boot option is Win10. Connect the data drive up and I get the BIOS option screen by hitting F8 and I can boot into windows or Ubuntu. I've been thinking I should just clone the drive to a 1TB drive and replace the data drive. I get more kicking the can down the road but its the only real option I have if I can't get this fixed right.

Comment: Assuming your SSD main drive is device sda, and  has both Windows and Ubuntu installs on it, but just lacks grub, under Ubuntu, did you ever try to just run sudo grub-install /dev/sda   ?   That may be all it takes.

Comment: sudo grub-install /dev/sda worked! Thank you thank you!! I've been chasing this problem off and on for a year and you solved it with a single post. I'm not very good with the terminal commands but I should be. I was a computer programmer many years ago, like before there were GUI's.

Comment: Seems I have one lingering problem. I've installed the 1tb drive to replace the failing 500gb drive but I can't delete anything from that drive. Seems it has been locked. Looking at the permissions it says it cannot be determined. WTH?

Comment: I solved this problem by booting into win10 (I have dual boot) and set the permissions from there. Ubuntu/Linux gave me no options to set a drive permission, just the folders, and even then I couldn't cut/move/delete anything. All is good now. Thank you ubfan1 for helping out with the sudo grub-install /dev/sda command suggestion, it did the trick. I just may upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04LTS later in the day. What could go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

From the comment suggestion which worked:
Assuming your SSD main drive is device sda, and has both Windows and Ubuntu installs on it, but just lacks grub, run Ubuntu, start a terminal from the launcher or with ctrl-alt-t, and run:

```
 sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

That may be all it takes.